# How to create LINQ expression?

Tags: linq

I have IEnumerable sequence of `bids` each element of which has volume field.
How to skip all first element which have aggregated volume less the some treshold `skipVolume` using Linq?

So like:

```
bids.SkipWhile( sum of (s=>s.volume) skiped < skipVolume)
```

Comment: LINQ is not really suited for your aggregate calculation because you have to terminate it at a certain point (if you really really really wanted to, you could use Aggregate to return the index at which it is reached but you'd have an ugly lambda expression with conditions in it). I would first find the index at which the threshold is reached with a traditional loop and then use skip/take using that number (or just populate a new collection inside that loop).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `where` clause where you both compute the cumulative volume and test against the `skipVlolume`:

```
  var aggVolume = 0d;
  var subBids = bids.Where(x => {
    aggVolume += x.volume;
    return aggVolume >= skipVolume;
  })
```